# I want to append the query string on a URL to all anchor links on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I am trying to append a query string on a URL to all anchor links on page.  If the page URL was www.example.com/page?paramter1=variable&parameter2=variable2

The variables may change each time and it is to be used for analytics.

I would like all the other links on the page to automatically get **?paramter1=variable&parameter2=variable2** added to them when the page loads.

I had been playing around with the following script but i can't seem get variable '*myquerystringtoadd*' to be populated by the query string in the URL which I don't necessarily know what the parameters would be so it is the whole query string.

```
var querystring = 'myquerystringtoadd';

$('a').each(function()
{
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
 href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
 $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please add more code to demonstrate the issue. Your code https://jsfiddle.net/d89kgvr1/ works as expected. Did you put the jquery code inside of doc ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `querySelectorAll` in vanilla javascript instead of jquery.  Also, kill your leading '?' in `querystring`.  And if part of your question involves how to get the querystring from the current page's url, use `window.location.search`.

In the snippet below, you have some google search anchors.  One searches 'x', and the other searches 'y'.  Your query string further specifies that in both anchors, you want a safe search for images.

```js
// You will use window.location.search
let querystring = '?tbm=isch&safe=active' 

if(querystring.startsWith('?'))
    querystring = querystring.replace('?', '');

for(let a of document.querySelectorAll('a')) {
    a.href += 
        (a.href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + 
        querystring;
}
```

```html
<a href='https://www.google.com/search?q=x'>search x images safely</a><br/>
<a href='https://www.google.com/search?q=y'>search y images safely</a>
```

Note: You may have noticed that I'm editing this question a lot, but it's just to to work with google query strings.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I may have written the question slightly incorrectly.  I am trying to populate all the links on the page with whatever the querystring is which may be different each time.  Its more more for tracking variables that people may use on links coming to the landing page.

Comment: When you say 'whatever the querystring is which may be different each time', are you not talking about the result of `window.location.search`?.  If so, look at the comment above `let querystring =`

Comment: I was trying to use something like this getParams(window.location.href); to pull the query string an populate each of the anchor links in the rest of the page with it.

Comment: @GregStaunton. that's not what I asked.  In my code above, can you please replace the value of `querystring` with `window.location.search` and tell me if it's working for you?

Comment: it works, you are a god amongst ants!  Thank you so much!